# Allocate Static Shared Memory using MapViewOfFile

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files, data-segment

How can I allocated shared memory to a static buffer like the following but using CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile.

```
#pragma data_seg(".ABC")
__declspec (dllexport) char buffer[10000]  = {0};
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "-section:.ABC,rws")
```

The goal is to create a static shared buffer that is shared between C++ and FORTRAN applications, like it's done when using `data_seg`. When creating a dynamic allocated buffer, FORTRAN gets tricky because you need to de-reference the pointer, which is also doable, but it's not what I want.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Are we supposed to know what `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` are?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Functions of the WinAPI: [CreateFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) and [MapViewOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx). OP: What is your goal, to share with what? Could you please provide more information?

Comment: The goal is to create a static shared buffer that is shared between C++ and FORTRAN applications like it's done when using data_seg.  When creating a dynamic allocated buffer, FORTRAN gets tricky because you need to de-reference the pointer, which is also doable but it's not what I want.

Comment: @user3716892 what makes you think `MapViewOfFile` will be any better? You will still have a pointer to dynamically allocated memory (within the system paging file). It won't be static.

Comment: I guess that's the problem. MapViewOfFile is dynamic and has to be de-referenced in FORTRAN to be accessed.  I can continue to use shared section but this has another weird behavior.  When I set the value using Visual Studio 2015 debugger, the memory shows it changed and the changed value is available to the application I'm debugging BUT the value is not viewable in other applications pointing to the same shared section.  Changing the value in the compiled code works fine (viewable by both applications).

Comment: See this link for an example of the above problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462106/setting-a-value-in-the-debugger-of-a-shared-section

Comment: The other problem with a shared section is that it is insecure; if a different user is running the same program, that user's program will be sharing memory with your program.  MapViewOfFileEx allows you to put the shared memory mapping at a fixed location, but that runs the risk that the location you've chosen might already be in use, and I don't know whether that will work with FORTRAN anyway.  Edit: huh.  Actually, that should work.  I'll post an answer.

Comment: ... never mind.  I thought you could free the memory already occupied by the buffer, since it is in a separate section anyway, and remap it as a view of a file mapping.  This can't be done, or at least not with the supported API.  (It might be possible using undocumented functions, since the Windows loader manages it somehow.)  The problem is that the entire executable is loaded as a single memory allocation, which means you can't free just one section.

Comment: (Are you sure modern FORTRAN compilers don't provide any solution to this problem?  There's really no way to access a dynamically-located buffer as if it were a statically-located buffer?)

Comment: ... can you reference a static buffer that is located in a DLL?

Comment: Harry Johnston, see below.  Modern FORTRAN does support it but in an executable statement.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent Win32 API calls would look like this:

```
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

HANDLE hMapping = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, &sa, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 10000, TEXT("ABC")); 
if (!hMapping) ... // error handling

char *buffer = (char*) MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 10000);
if (!buffer) ... // error handling

// use buffer as needed... 

UnmapViewOfFile(buffer);
CloseHandle(hMapping);
```

Both apps would have to call `CreateFileMapping()` with the same `lpName` value to gain access to the same mapping object in the system kernel. Whichever app calls `CreateFileMapping()` first will create the object, and the second app will get a handle to the existing object. Then, `MapViewOfFile()` maps memory access within the calling process to that object.  In this way, both apps are using shared memory with each other. When one app writes data into the object, the other app will see it.

Comment: I know that's how to create a shared file mapping but the problem is that I don't want a dynamic pointer (char *buffer).  Probably what I want is not possible.

Comment: @user: That doesn't make much sense. There is little difference between the pointer `buffer` in this answer and the `buffer` array in the question. If you absolutely need to access the file mapping object as an array, you could easily cast the pointer to a reference to an array type. Or simply index the pointer. `buffer[0] = 'A';` is legal for the pointer and the array.

Comment: @IInspectable: what you say is true for C and C++, but remember, the OP is asking about Fortran instead.

Comment: If the OP is having difficulty accessing the memory from FORTRAN, why does the compile time type in C or C++ matter? It's just a block of memory. I also don't understand the significant difference between a file mapping object and a shared segment in the question. Both provide a block of memory at an address, that's only known at runtime.

Comment: The difference is that a buffer array in FORTRAN can be accessed through a common block as apposed to a pointer buffer which needs an execution call to cast from C.   I don't want to have an execution call since I'm trying to create a precompiler that only processes variable declarations.